# Xcode SVN Error: 160028 Transaction is out of date

Tags: iphone, svn, xcode

Description: Out of date:'the file name' in transaction '2639-1'

Anyone can help?  Thanks

Comment: In what context is this occurring?

Answer (score 2):

Run update before commit. This problem can be solved.
Thank you for your attention.